# EmacsでC-x C-fすると、バッファが二分割する動作の抑制

Tags: emacs, elisp

お世話になります。

Emacsを使っているのですが、新しいパソコンに新しいバージョンをインストールすると、C-x C-fでファイルやディレクトリを開いたときに、現在開いているバッファが上下に二分割し（C-x 2の状態）、その一方に新しいファイルが、別の方には前のバッファが表示されるようになりました。

なるほど、その方が便利なのかなと思ってしばらく使っていたのですが、そうしたくない時（全画面に新しいファイルやディレクトリを表示したいとき）の方が多いので、上記の新しい動作を抑制したいと思います。

この動作を抑制する.emacs.d/init.elの設定はあるでしょうか。
また、このような疑問が新たに出てきた場合、自分で回答を見出す方法はあるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: init.el を全く読み込まない状態で emacs を起動しても、そのような動作になっている感じでしょうか？

Comment: `M-x describe-variable` を実行して、`find-file-hook` を入力した結果を確認すると何か判るかもしれません。

Comment: 私の手元のemacs(emacs25.2.2, Win10/WSL2/ubuntu18.04, GUIなし, 端末全画面)では再現しませんでした。OSとかemacsのバージョンとかの情報も役立つかも知れません。（最新版を新たに入れてまで再現してみよう、というところまで意欲を掻き立てられるわけではないので、手元にあるので試しに叩いてみたレベルです）
調べたい場合、自分なら、"C-x C-f"に割当たってるelispの関数を特定して、その関数をdescribeして読む、とかですかね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者です。
コメントでヒントをいただいて分かりました。
Emacs25＝＞26の変更点でpopwinの挙動がおかしくなるという問題があったそうです。
私の場合は.emacs.d/init.elを

```
  (require 'popwin) 
- (setq display-buffer-function 'popwin:display-buffer) 
+ (popwin-mode 1)
```

のように修正すると直りました。

Answer (score 0):

オイラんところの Emacs-26.1 build1 i686-w64-mingw32 で `C-x C-f` つまり `find-file` を呼んでも、それだけでは画面分割しないです。というわけで、その挙動を示す `Emacs` バージョンが質問に記載されていると読者の側で再現試験ができます（ないと無理）

---

日本語で検索してヒットしないなら、英語で検索するっす。この例では検索キーワードとして `emacs` `find-file` `split` がぱっと思いつくはず。すると
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879921/
とかヒットするですね。これによると画面が広いと自動分割するような説明があります（が、オイラんとこで再現しないのでなんとも）

Answer (score 0):

質問者です。

実務で焦っていたので、質問の基本をだいぶ外した質問をしてしまいました。
改めて情報です。

**Emacsのバージョン**

M-x emacs-version

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13) of 2019-12-15
```

**OSのバージョン（Ubuntu）**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

**.emacs.d/init.elを読み込まないとどうなるか**

```
$ emacs -q
```

で起動したところ、問題の動作は起きませんでした。

**問題の原因**

.emacs.d/init.elを少しずつ削除して問題箇所を選んだところ、以下の部分に当たりました。

これは、google-translateを使ってカーソル位置の英語を日本語にするもので、以下はC-c wを割り当てています。
もとはるびきちさんのブログからいただいたものですが、ある程度改造して分からなくなってしまっています。

```
;(require 'google-translate)
;(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") 'google-translate-at-point)
;(global-set-key (kbd "C-c W") 'google-translate-query-translate)
;
;  (require 'popwin)
;  (setq display-buffer-function 'popwin:display-buffer)
;  
;  (require 'google-translate)
;  (require 'google-translate-default-ui)
;  
;  (defvar google-translate-english-chars "[:ascii:]"
;    "これらの文字が含まれているときは英語とみなす")
;  (defun google-translate-enja-or-jaen (&optional string)
;    "regionか現在位置の単語を翻訳する。C-u付きでquery指定も可能"
;    (interactive)
;    (setq string
;          (cond ((stringp string) string)
;                (current-prefix-arg
;                 (read-string "Google Translate: "))
;                ((use-region-p)
;                 (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))
;                (t
;                 (thing-at-point 'word))))
;    (let* ((asciip (string-match
;                    (format "\\`[%s]+\\'" google-translate-english-chars)
;                    string)))
;      (run-at-time 0.1 nil 'deactivate-mark)
;      (google-translate-translate
;       (if asciip "en" "ja")
;       (if asciip "ja" "en")
;       string)))
;  
;  (push '("\*Google Translate\*" :height 0.5 :stick t) popwin:special-display-config)
;  
;  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") 'google-translate-enja-or-jaen)
;  
;  
;  ;;;;; Fix error of "Failed to search TKK"
;  (defun google-translate--get-b-d1 ()
;      ;; TKK='427110.1469889687'
;    (list 427110 1469889687))
```

これをコメント化したところ、問題の現象は起きなくなりました。
google-translateは使えた方が便利なので、その後はさらに追求します。
コメントをくださったみなさん、ありがとうございました。

ただ、Emacsの以前のバージョンでは上記のelispを読み込んでも、表題の動作が起きなかったことは確かです。
なので、元質問のようになってしまいました。
どのバージョンからアップしたのかは、あいにく覚えていません（スミマセン）。
なんとも甘い質問者で、反省いたします。

Comment: 自分も同じ現象にあった経験があります。どうやら 25→26の変更点でC-x C-f (find-file)周りの挙動が変わったらしく `(setq display-buffer-function 'popwin:display-buffer)` の箇所が質問タイトルのような動作を起こす原因だったようです（自分の設定ファイルにメモ書きが残っていた）。

Comment: ありがとうございます！「popwin Emacs26」で検索すると以下のページに当たりました。
https://blog.shibayu36.org/entry/2018/12/25/193000

私の上の.emacs.d/init.elの場合は

  (require 'popwin)
  ;(setq display-buffer-function 'popwin:display-buffer)
  (popwin-mode 1)

のように修正でうまくいきました。快適です。ありがとうございます！